# SQL Concat Distinct results in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, xml-serialization, ibm-midrange, substr

I am using the below statement in my query but need to select distinct values in my concatenation string.

```
substr( 
    xmlserialize( 
        xmlagg( xmltext( concat( ', ', item) ) ) as varchar( 1024 ) 
    ), 
3 )
```

I have to do it that way because I'm running on a DB2 AS/400 database.

Right now my results look like this:

```
yellow,red,red,yellow,blue,yellow,blue,red
```

I need it to return only distinct values, like this:

```
yellow,red,blue
```

Comment: I guess you'll need to return distinct `ITEM` values from the subselect. Since you didn't publish your complete query text you'll have to figure out by yourself how that works.

Comment: @mustaccio is gently (and correctly) suggesting that you edit your question and post a bit more of the code.  I'm going to add that you aren't running against an AS/400.  This matters because looking for examples is very hit or miss with the AS/400 search item.  DB2 for IBM i documentation is found in the Knowledge Center: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i/welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out I used a sub select to find the results and than selected from those results the concatention

```
SELECT 
   CUSTOMER, 
   substr( xmlserialize( xmlagg( xmltext( concat( ', ', item) ) ) as varchar( 1024 ) ), 3)
FROM
   (
SELECT CUSTOMER, ITEM
FROM ORDERS
WHERE
   ITEM LIKE 'C%'
GROUP BY CUSTOMER, ITEM)
GROUP BY CUSTOMER;
```

Comment: If you `GROUP BY` every column in the `SELECT` list, use `DISTINCT` instead (I'd imagine that the db produces the same plan, it's more of a semantic thing).